# When a slope doesn't match a visual trend

Tags: least-squares

I am trying to determine the linear slope between two variables in a dataset. The ordinary least squares (OLS) method returns a slope which does not appear to fit the trend that one's eye sees in the data--the relationship looks steeper. I have tried using also a Theil-Sen estimator, but it gives a similar value to the OLS.

Are there any other ways to estimate the slope? Or is my eye just being fooled by a few points?

[image]

Comment: The problem is, in part, like an election. In this example we, and you, can't even tell easily from the scatter plot how many voters are going which way in the central cluster of the data. The problem is also, in part, one of leverage. Some of those points near the periphery will lever the line towards them in the least squares case; the comparison with Theil-Sen gives a fair sense of that. It may be that you don't even have a linear pattern overall; some kind of kernel or similar regression would be a useful check. Can you post the data?

Comment: OLS minimizes sum of squared **vertical** distances between the data points and the fitted values. Sometimes the eye "prefers" other distances like the shortest line between the regression line and the data points in an $(x,y)$ plane.

Comment: I don't know how anyone could provide any recommendations without a clear understanding of what the purpose of your analysis is.  What is it that you are trying to do, and why do you think it is important that the estimated slope match your subjective view of where the best fit line should be?

Comment: This technique is called "regression" precisely because the fitted lines tend to be more level than they eye would suggest (they "regress to the mean"). The amount of leveling depends on how scattered the points are. Perhaps the very best answer you can get is to learn what regression is really doing, so that you can determine whether regression or some other technique is appropriate for your data and your objectives.

Comment: As several people have pointed out, you would probably do best to learn more about what OLS regression does & why the answer you found is the right answer to that question. However, what I suspect is going on here is that there is a horizontal band of data 3/4 of the way up the plot that seems to be behaving differently from the rest. You could ask a new Q regarding how to detect & deal w/ that. (If so, your Q would be about detecting latent groups / clusters, &/or dealing with bivariate outliers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [orthogonal regression](http://www.nlreg.com/orthogonal.htm), which fits a line that minimizes the sum of the lengths of orthogonal projections on the line (instead of the sum of squared errors, as OLS does). In R (borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097904/452096)):

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- rnorm(20)
yy <- rnorm(20)
r <- prcomp( ~ xx + yy )
slope <- r$rotation[2,1] / r$rotation[1,1]
intercept <- r$center[2] - slope*r$center[1]
plot(xx,yy)
abline(lm(yy~xx))
abline(a=intercept,b=slope,lty=2)
legend("bottomleft",lwd=1,lty=1:2,legend=c("OLS","Orthogonal"))
```

[image: OLS vs orthogonal]